# How do i reload app.config File data

Tags: c#

i have a program that edits app.config file and save it. however i can edit and save but I can't reload the app.config data without restarting the app.
i tried couple of ways.i'm not sure what is wrong

this is my code..

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
     UpdateConfig("IP",radtxtIP.Text, "myApp.exe");
     UpdateConfig("port", radtxtPort.Text, "myApp.exe");
     LoadConfigData();
}
private void UpdateConfig(string key, string value, string fileName)
{
    var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(fileName);
    configFile.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
    configFile.Save(); 
}

 public void LoadConfigData()
 {
      ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
      Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
      radtxtIP.Text =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IP"];
      radtxtPort.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["port"];  
 }
```

when i click save button it gives me old settings. 
i added this code after reading some questions in stackoverflow,but no use

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```

do I need to make a new instance of ConfigurationManager? 
is it ok the way i use Configuration data.?
my app uses app.config data in many places. so have to restart the app when I change my configuration data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Some thing like this, and hope this one easy

```
class SettingsService
{

    public static string GetSetting(string key)
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        return config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value.ToString();
    }

    public static void UpdateConfig(string key, string value )
    {
        var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        configFile.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
        configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); 
    }
}
```

Can update appsettings by calling `UpdateConfig("key1","value")` method 
and can get setting by using this `GetSetting("key")`

Note:- when use VS to run application it's updates ApplicationName.vshost.exe(Config file) only

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpfull
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.refreshsection.aspx

Please make sure you load the new settings as shown below

```
// Get the AppSettings section.
AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection(sectionName);
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, It really helped.  `AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection(sectionName)`  but this code give some thing like this `<appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="hard codded text (A)" />
  </appSettings>` i want to key values separately